# Tab like Android in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, storyboard

I am Working on Tab like android in `iOS` `Swift3`. I have installed `XLPagerTabStrip` successful but facing problem:

> terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'child1'

Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip
class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

let customPurpleColor = UIColor(red:0.13 , green : 0.03 , blue : 0.25 , alpha : 1.0)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = customPurpleColor
    settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 1.0
    settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailiableWidth = true
    settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell : ButtonBarViewCell? , newCell : ButtonBarViewCell?
        , progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex : Bool , animated : Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else {return}
        oldCell?.label.textColor = .black
        newCell?.label.textColor = self?.customPurpleColor
        }
}
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child_1 = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "child1")
    let child_2 = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "child2")
    return [child_1 , child_2]
        }
}
```

ChildViewController1.swift:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip


class ChildViewController1: UIViewController , IndicatorInfoProvider{
 func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title : "child1")
}
}
```

ChildViewController2.swift:

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class ChildViewController2: UIViewController , IndicatorInfoProvider{
func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title : "child1")
}
}
```

I have used the `UIScrollView` and `collectionView` to buttonBarView in `Main.storyboard`. Because I am new to iOS Development that's why I'm not getting why this error occurs?

Comment: please do not uses tag which are not related with the question

Comment: you need to set viewcontroller identifier in storyboard .

Comment: you can try this : https://github.com/EndouMari/TabPageViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ViewController's identifier as below :

[image]

Comment: I set Storyboard ID to child1 but it show the same error

Comment: Is the storyboard in which your "child1" controller exists really named "Main"?

Comment: When app Crash it stop in Line :-class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate